# Multi-language support for different map views with HERE

Tags: here-api

currently I am trying to display the HERE map with the JavaScript API in German.
According to this [example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/map-multi-language-support) it is possible to change the language of the map. This works fine for German when the map is first loaded. However, when the map view is changed e.g. to 'Satellite' these settings seem to be lost. In all the multi-language examples I found online, the option to change the map view is disabled. Can the language be set for example to German for all the available views or is this customizing restricted to one view only and I need to disable the other views?

Thanks in advance, Team DG7

Answer (score 2):

Below is the entire sample code to have all views of the map in Chinese Language. You can change it according to your needs. 
Please use your own app id and app code. The main snippet in the below code is the createDefaultlayers where you speciy the language parameter for all layers.

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320,
  lg: 'CHI'
});
```

Happy Coding!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1533195059" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />
  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >

/**
 * Switches the map language to simplified Chinese
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 * @pama   {H.service.Platform} platform    A stub class to access HERE services
 */
function switchMapLanguage(map, platform){
  var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({
      type: 'base'
    }),
    // Our layer will load tiles from the HERE Map Tile API
    chineseMapLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'normal.day',
      pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
      'png8',
      {lg: 'CHI', ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320}
    );
  map.setBaseLayer(chineseMapLayer);

  // Display default UI components on the map and change default
  // language to simplified Chinese.
  // Besides supported language codes you can also specify your custom translation
  // using H.ui.i18n.Localization.
  var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers, 'zh-CN');

}




/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'YOUR-APP-ID',
  app_code: 'YOUR-APP-CODE',
  useHTTPS: true
});
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
  tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
  ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320,
  lg: 'CHI'
});

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Hong Kong.
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:22.2783, lng:114.1588},
  zoom: 12,
  pixelRatio: pixelRatio
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Now use the map as required...
switchMapLanguage(map , platform);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```